# Open authencation window in Embeded browser

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am working on google drive API. I have found that some of the old code using NativeApplicationClient. so I would like to know new API’s support “NativeApplicationClient”.
I found that new code is using “GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker” . I am working on WPF windows application and I want to launch the url from my own browser. How can I achieve the old feature using by new APIs.

I know that old API’s support NativeApplicationClient and I can generate the url and launch it on WPF my own browser.  Just wanted to know what is the latest approach I need to follow to achieve the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

At this time the Google .net Client library doesn't support opening the authentication in an embedded browser.

Issue request:  [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker in embedded browser?](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/547)